# What does the Maven warning, "The artifact...has been relocated to..." mean?

Tags: java, maven

I am getting these warnings when I attempt to run package.

```
[WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2

[WARNING] The artifact axis:axis-ant:jar:1.4 has been relocated to org.apache.axis:axis-ant:jar:1.4
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

in your dependency declaration change `groupId` from `org.apache.commons` to `commons-io`

Comment: Did this occur because the location changed in the remote repository to one with a different groupId?

Comment: Can you look at another Maven question of mine?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623900/how-do-i-add-a-jar-file-to-my-local-maven-repository-using-eclipse-m2e-on-luna-s

Comment: What fooled me was that when you do a search of Maven Central, the summary list says that latest `commons-io:commons-io` was in 2005. You have to drill down to find out that's not true! http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccommons-io

Comment: no single "org.apache.commons:commons-io" in dependency:tree, however warning comes up somehow... And it is really annoying!!!

Comment: @mirec It's possible that it's a hidden dependency, for me it was an older version of Querydsl that had it.

Answer (score 2):

JFYI: it works this way: [org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io/1.3.2/jar) pom contains new groupId/artifactId of artifact to avoid possible jar hell with intersecting classpaths from different artifacts:

```
  <distributionManagement>
    <relocation>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <message>https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-244</message>
    </relocation>
  </distributionManagement>
```

and maven replaces the dependency automatically.
Another example: [org.hibernate:hibernate-validator](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/6.1.6.Final/jar) relocates to another groupId.