# How do I add a jar file to my local Maven repository using Eclipse m2e on Luna Service (4.4.1)?

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse

I am getting an warning message because I manually added a jar file to my local maven repository.

[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/netsuite/nsws-2014/1.0/nsws-2014-1.0.pom

[WARNING] The POM for com.netsuite:nsws-2014:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available

How do I properly add a jar file to my local Maven repository using Eclipse m2e on Luna Service (4.4.1)?

Like can I use the builder?

[image: install:install-file]

Comment: did you declare it as `<scope>system</scope>`

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>com.netsuite</groupId>  
       <artifactId>nsws-2014</artifactId>  
       <version>1</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: if I do that, then it wants a build path.  Here is the error:   Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.netsuite:nsws-2014:jar is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The local Maven repository is effectively a standard Maven repository; as such, it must adhere to a particular format (there are a few Maven-compatible repository formats).

Dropping files into a repository isn't going to cut it, unless you are able to mimic the creation of additional artifacts in accordance to the Maven repository format that you use.

The only foolproof way to do so would be to use the `install:install-file` goal, as specified here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

To do this using m2e, you need to use a small hack. Create a Maven Launch configuration. In the "base directory" field, type in a value that will always resolve to a real directory, such as `${workspace_loc}`. In the "Goals", field, type `install:install-file`, and then add the parameters (see the link in the paragraph below) in the "parameters" table (use the "Add" button to add parameters). Then run this launch configuration.

Comment: Isaac, I added an image to the question. Can you look at it and tell me what I may have done wrong?

Comment: Omit the "-D" before each parameter name.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue.  I see from the verbose that is was installed into the local maven repository.

Answer (score 1):

You should add jar to your local repository like:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=... -DartifactId=... -Dversion=... -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=... -DgeneratePom=true
```

`-DgeneratePom=true` genertes POM automatically...

Comment: I don't have maven installed, so I can't call commands on the command line.  How would I call that command in the current version of eclipse?

Comment: @pitchblack408 if you don't have maven installed how did you add the jar to your repository?  Whatever your answer is, would be where I would be trying to add the generate POM command.  Good Luck

Comment: Eclipse comes with maven built into their ide now days.  But you can not open the command prompt and run maven commands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `<scope>system</scope>` like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netsuite</groupId>
    <artifactId>nsws-2014</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>/path/to/your.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That may resolve the warning, but it won't add the nsws-2014 jar to the repository. Is there are way to add it to the the jar to the repository by using eclipse?

Comment: if you are installing then you don't need the scope=system and systempath tags, you could install it like shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706173/maven-ojbc-6-jar-not-found-in-central-repository

Comment: But is there a way to perform that in eclipse using eclipse?

Comment: certainly is, right click on your project, run as, maven build ... (with 3 dots) and type in everything except `mvn` from that command